Azure - Blob Storage - Index Tags - How do I remove them
I have an Azure Storage Account setup and store pdf files in a blob container.  Here is the config.

I'm using a c# solution to insert the files into blob storage.  I have a few million pdf files in blob storage.
Initially I was storing Index Tags against each blob so that I could search for them quickly.  I have since moved this metadata into a Sql Server database and no longer have need for Index Tags.
I tried to remove the Index Tags with various code samples I found online including the following code:
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
    BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);

    await foreach (BlobItem blobItem in containerClient.GetBlobsAsync(states: BlobStates.All))
    {
        BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(blobItem.Name);
        await blobClient.SetTagsAsync(new Dictionary<string, string>());
        Console.WriteLine($"Removed tags from blob: {blobItem.Name}");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("All index tags removed.");
}

The Tags look like they are no longer attached to the blobs but I am still being billed for Index Tags (which is pricey for the volume of files I have).
Does anyone know why?
Have I missed something in the Tag removal process?
Cheers,
Rod


The Tags look like they are no longer attached to the blobs but I am still being billed for Index Tags (which is pricey for the volume of files I have).
Does anyone know why? Have I missed something in the Tag removal process?

The above code with blobClient.SetTagsAsync(tags) is correct for removing the all-index tag from the list of blobs using C#.
If you need to check whether the blob index tags are removed or not, you can use the below code.
Code:
string connectionString = "xxxx";
string containerName = "xxxxx";
BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);

await foreach (BlobItem blobItem in containerClient.GetBlobsAsync(states: BlobStates.All))
{
    BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(blobItem.Name);
    try
    {
        var tags = await blobClient.GetTagsAsync();
        if (tags.Value.Tags.Count > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Blob '{blobItem.Name}' has the following tags:");
            foreach (var tag in tags.Value.Tags)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"- {tag.Key}: {tag.Value}");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Blob '{blobItem.Name}' has no tags.");
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Error checking tags for blob '{blobItem.Name}': {ex.Message}");
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("Tag check completed.");

Output:
Blob 'data.zip' has no tags.
Blob 'example.csv' has no tags.
Blob 'sample3.csv' has no tags.
Tag check completed.


According to this MS-Document.

Azure Blob Storage charges for the storage of index tags on a monthly basis. The cost depends on the average number of index tags stored per day throughout the billing cycle.
So, if you remove the index tags from your blobs, it may take some time for the billing to reflect the changes you made.

Reference:
Set Blob Tags (REST API) - Azure Storage | Microsoft Learn

If you’ve confirmed that all tags have been removed and also you didn't see any changes in your bill at the beginning of the next month, I recommend you open a support ticket with Azure support team.
